# Using automator, sort objects by type into type folders, inside subfolders

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

long time no ask! Anyway, I've been tasked with a project that involves sorting folders into new folders based on type. I've been working on an Automator action, but I haven't had much success. What I'd like to have the folder structure look like is:

> Main Folder
>
> > ```
> >            -Movie
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >                -Project name
> > >           -Photo
> > >                -Project name
> > >           -Document
> > >                 -Project name
> > >           -Audio
> > >                -Project name
> > > ```

I can sort my folder into the audio/photo/movie/document folders, but I cannot make new subfolders and move my items into them, I simply lack the knowledge. Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks!

EDIT: here is what I have so far: https://mega.co.nz/#!HQN1GK6C!WvBvDOAt_5116hAoIAIhXTWIfg9fNKjxZxIgG-AHWRk

Comment: you tagged applescript, but want to use automator. It can be done with both. share what you've done so far so there isn't wasted time on anyones behalf

Comment: @soulshined I tagged it as both, not knowing what would be better to use. I'll upload the workflow.

Comment: upload it as a workflow not as an app

Comment: @soulshined in Yosemite, (for me) it saves workflows as apps, you should be able to open it in Workflow (drag the app on the Automator icon)

Comment: you can elect to save it as a workflow when you save it.

Comment: disregard...the first download was corrupted